# how to remove "posts" option from dashboard of wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a service website. It needs no blog post options. So I want to remove posts option from my WordPress dashboard. Is it possible? How?
[image: WP Admin menu]

Comment: Visit this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just hide the menu by adding this code to your functions.php

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_posts_menu');
function remove_posts_menu() 
{
    remove_menu_page('edit.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_menus(){
remove_menu_page('edit.php'); }
add_action('admin_menu','remove_menus');
```

you can try this code.